# If $a_1,...,a_r$ is an $M$-regular sequence of maximal length, $M/(a_1,...,a_r)M$ has finite length.

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian, dimension-theory-algebra

Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over a Noetherian local ring $R$, and $a_1,...,a_r$ be an $M$-regular sequence of maximal length. Then, $M/(a_1,...,a_r)M$ has finite length?

I guess it is not true. If the statement is true, by the dimension theorem, dim$M\leq r$=depth$M$. And we know depth$M\leq$dim$M$, so dim$M$=depth$M$. But not every finitely generated module over a Noetherian local ring is Cohen-Macaulay.

Comment: Consider $r=0$ and $M=R$. What we have now is a local ring of depth zero. Is $R$ artinian, that is, is $\dim R=0$? Of course not! The well known example $R=K[x,y]_{(x,y)}/(x^2,xy)$ does the job.

Comment: Thank you very much for another example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, this is false.  For an explicit counterexample, let $(A,\mathfrak{m})$ be any Noetherian local ring of positive dimension and let $R=A[x]/((x^2)+\mathfrak{m}x)$.  Then taking $M=R$, there is no nontrivial $M$-regular sequence, since every non-unit element of $R$ annihilates $x$.  So, the quotient you consider is just $R$ itself, which does not have finite length since $A$ has positive dimension.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification!